# Create a simple form

Tags: symfony

Just want to create a simple contact form in Symfony 2.1. How?

ContactForm.php:

```
namespace frontend\mainBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ContactForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('subject', 'textarea');
        $builder->add('email', 'email');
        $builder->add('message', 'textarea');
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'contact';
    }

}
```

DefaultController.php

```
namespace frontend\mainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use mylib\DataFormatChecker;
use frontend\mainBundle\Form\ContactForm;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

        public function contactAction(Request $request)
    {

        $task = array();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder(new ContactForm(), $task);  
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

            //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('frontendmainBundle:Default:contact.html.php', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
    }
}
```

Error:
 Declaration of frontend\mainBundle\Form\ContactForm::buildForm() must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::buildForm(Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) in line 8 in ContactForm.php.

What is wrong?

Sorry, used to symfony 1.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with symfony, actually. It occurs because declaration of `buildForm` function does not match with that of base class (AbstractType). The first parameter of `buildForm` must be an instance of `FormBuilderInterface` whereas your first parameter is instance of `FormBuilder`

```php
// ...
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ContactForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks but one more little problem:  Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder::createView(). What do I have to change in DefaultController.php?

Comment: @craphunter, replace `$this->createFormBuilder` with `$this->createForm`